# PartialView passing Customized List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 Databases using EF w/ MVC4. I have searched all through SO to avail. I need to return a list of Alerts to a partial view. However the Alerts should be filtered by a specific username with a specific identifier. The View is strongly typed, and I'd like to keep it like that.

I have the LINQ query returning to a List and it's the list of the usernames associated with the specific id. You can see in the second case statement where the two table lookup needs to go.I want to do this without a viewmodel class.

Here is the code:

```
    public PartialViewResult DashboardAlerts()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AlertsContext>(null);
        AlertsContext db = new AlertsContext();

        Database.SetInitializer<MemberUsersContext>(null);
        MemberUsersContext mdb = new MemberUsersContext();

        var members = new List<MemberUsers>(mdb.MemberUsers);
        var alerts = new List<Alerts>(db.Alerts);

        var query = from x in alerts
                    join y in members
                    on x.username equals y.username
                    where y.clubID == (int)Session["ClubID"]
                    select new { username = y.username};

        var list = query.ToList();

        switch (Session["RoleName"].ToString())
        {
            case "GMC Admin": return PartialView(db.Alerts.ToList());
            case "Club Admin": return //return db.Alerts.ToList() that has only usernames from query.ToList();
            default: return PartialView(db.Alerts.Where(x => x.username == User.Identity.Name).ToList());
        }
    }
```

Bottom Line: I want to cross reference db.Alerts with only values from query list's username property.

Comment: Have you considered using the ViewBag to send it to the View?

Comment: Can I keep it strongly typed with a ViewBag?

Comment: Viewbag and model are seperate ways of passing data to the view and are mutually exclusive.  Since the viewbag is a dynamic object you can just add the item to the ViewBag in the Action and then in the view check to see if the value exists and do code based on that.

Comment: So you want to use MVC without the M?  But then you want a strongly typed view against a Model.  Strange to say the least.  Why do you want to do it without a ViewModel?  I say this because most likely there is a MUCH better way to do what you want with a ViewModel, but you probably have some idea that makes you think you can't use a ViewModel.

Comment: @Kenneth, I went the ViewBag route and created a ViewModel Class ultimately. Thanks for the suggestion(s). I didn't want to stray away from the original IENumerator Scaffolding created with the Edit, Details, and Delete tempaltes included in MVC4, but now that I've learned more, passing an IEnumerator Model doesn't really matter with ViewBag. Essentially I can take parts of the IEnumerator strongly typed model and the ViewBag both!

Comment: Thanks,  Professionally I need to say that I would prefer to pass ALL data to the view using the model.  Its far cleaner that way and easier to handle in the view, but the ViewBag works in a pinch if you can't update the model for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, you use want to narrow down the alerts to the ones where you have the usename in query.  looks like you already have that done, just dont select the username, but the alert instead

```
var query = from x in alerts
                join y in members
                on x.username equals y.username
                where y.clubID == (int)Session["ClubID"]
                select x;
```

that will return you the alerts rather than the list of usernames.